# How to monitor file changes with HHVM?

Tags: php, inotify, hhvm

PHP has the [`inotify`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.inotify.php) extension, but HHVM does not support it.

How can I monitor a file at least for `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event on HHVM?

```
<?php // sample inotify code for PHP

$fd = inotify_init();
$watch_descriptor = inotify_add_watch($fd, __FILE__, IN_ATTRIB);
touch(__FILE__); // generate an event
$events = inotify_read($fd);
var_dump($events);
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/book.inotify.php)?

Comment: @Prasanth Yes, and if you go a bit [deeper](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.inotify-init.php) you will see a big warning saying "NOT SUPPORTED IN HHVM". That's the hole purpose of the question.

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, the *inotify* extension is not currently supported in HHVM. It is possible that the HHVM community will write an HNI extension supporting the API. HHVM already uses inotify, when available, internally for its "statcache" code (e.g. for caching lstat() information). Thus, the build environment is already setup to detect inotify's availability. Leveraging this would make writing a native extension easier than starting from scratch.

Until then, one alternative would be to use watchman in combination with your PHP code. In a push model, watchman executes a PHP script based on [triggers](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/trigger.html) you've previously configured. In a pull/poll model, you could [query](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/socket-interface.html) watchman over a socket. One advantage to using watchman is support for more operating systems than just Linux. The performance of using watchman versus a native inotify extension will be workload dependent.